# SignalR 2.0 Silverlight Client HubConnection CookieContainer

Tags: silverlight, signalr, silverlight-5.0, signalr-hub

```
 var connection = new HubConnection(hostAddress)
 {
     CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
 };
 cookieContainer.Add(...);
```

After updating SignalR 1.1.3 -> SignalR 2.x.x, it seems that the HubConnection class property CookieContainer doesn't work anymore.

(Tested: Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client, Silverlight -version)

You can add new CookieContainer and cookies as usual, but then in the runtime when you try to start the connection it just gives "this property is not implemented by this class"-exception.

So how can I set custom cookies with Silverlight SignalR 2.0 HubConnection -client?

Comment: I'm having this problem, too. Downgrading the SignalR client to 1.2.2 solves the CookieContainer issue for me. We'll find out if I need 2.x features later, but for now that's good enough.